# Pasar todos mis registros a un array y poder hacer Insert en Batch

Tags: php

estoy llenando una tabla de “llamadas” que se encuentra en un sistema CRM, lo que yo le paso es un array asociativo y hace el Insert correctamente, pero lo que no me gusta es que estoy pasando registro por registro. ¿Existe una posibilidad de primero guardar todos los registros en un array y después cuando ya estén todos los registros ahora si hacer el Insert?

A continuación, les anexo el código:

```
function get_llamadas($troncal, $RFC, $nombre_cuenta){
    $params = array(new xmlrpcval(array(
            "i_account"          => new xmlrpcval($troncal, "int"),
            "start_date"          => new xmlrpcval("00:00:00.000 GMT Mon Mar 09 2020", "string"),
            "end_date"          => new xmlrpcval("23:59:59.000 GMT Mon Mar 09 2020", "string"),
            "limit"          => new xmlrpcval("2", "int")
    ), 'struct'));


    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('getAccountCDRs', $params);

    $cli = new xmlrpc_client('https://sip.serv.net.mx/xmlapi/xmlapi');
    $cli->setSSLVerifyPeer(false);
    $cli->setSSLVerifyHost(false);
    $cli->setCredentials('usuario', 'password', CURLAUTH_DIGEST);

    $r = $cli->send($msg);

    $array_size = sizeof($r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array']);

    if ($r->faultCode([me])) {
      error_log("Fault. Code: " . $r->faultCode() . ", Reason: " . $r->faultString());
      return false;
    } else {
        print_r("tamaño de arreglo ".$array_size);
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
        $contador = 0;
        while ($contador < $array_size) {

            $ORIGEN = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['cli']->me[string]; 
            $id_CLIENTE = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['i_account']->me[int];//i_acooutn
            $fecha_inicio = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['connect_time']->me[string];
            $fecha_inicio1 = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($fecha_inicio));
            $duracion_segundos = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['billed_duration']->me[double];
            $duracion_minutos = round(($duracion_segundos * 1)/60);
            $DESTINO = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['cld_in']->me[string];

            $costo = $r->val->me['struct']['cdrs']->me['array'][$contador]->me['struct']['cost']->me[double];
            $TARIFA_BASE = round($costo);

            $MONTO_FINAL = $TARIFA_BASE * $duracion_minutos;

            $array_llamada = array( 'id_CLIENTE'=>$id_CLIENTE, 'RAZON_SOCIAL'=>$nombre_cuenta, 'ORIGEN'=>$ORIGEN, 'TIPO_TEL_DESTINO'=>"pendiete", 'DESTINO'=>$DESTINO, 'TIPO_TRAFICO'=>"pendiete", 'POBLACION_DESTINO'=>"pendiete", 'DURACION_MIN'=>$duracion_minutos, 'FECHA'=>$fecha_inicio1, 'TARIFA_BASE'=>$TARIFA_BASE, 'MONTO_FINAL'=>$MONTO_FINAL);

            print_r($array_llamada);
            conexion_creator($array_llamada);

            $contador++;  
        }

    }
}
```

Como pueden ver en el código estoy llamando a `conexion_creator($array_llamada);` para hacer el Insert pero de registro por registro, pero lo que requiero es hacer solo una llamada para sacar la conexión del while y ponerla abajo para solo crear una conexión.

Función que hace la conexión y a la vez hace el insert al sistema CRM

```
function conexion_creator($array_llamadas){

    $url = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/nombre/json/zoho-cdr/form/Detalle_de_Llamada1/record/add?authtoken=cfdgdfgdfgdfgg";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_llamadas);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
}
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Comment: puedes poner el codigo de conexion_llamada? esto ayudara en la respuesta :)

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Sí, existe la posibilidad de primero guardar todos los registros en un array y, cuando ya estén todos los registros, realizar el `INSERT`.

Para el primer paso te recomiendo leer todos los registros y e ir almacenándolos en un array más grande con `$array_total[]=$array_simple`.

Y, para el segundo, recorriendo `$array_total` con un `foreach()` para componer el query SQL, añadir varios registros simultáneamente con el `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1,campo2) VALUES
  ('dato1','dato2'),
  ('dato1','dato2'),
  ...
  ('dato1','dato2');
```

De hecho es muchísimo más rápido.

Ya me comentas si te funciona.

Comment: Entiendo tu solución, pero no que no quiero es volver a hacer iteraciones como me comentas tu con el foreach, más bien lo que necesito es pasarle el array con todos los registros a mi conexión solo hacer un solo insert del array con todos los registros sin la necesidad de estarlos iterando de nuevo. Te anexo mi conexión con Curl donde hago el insert al sistema CRM.

Comment: Listo ya anexe mi conexion al sistema CRM que a su vez hace el insert del registro, pero quiero mandar todos los registros en el array y no hacer insert de 1 por 1.

Comment: no necesitas ningun foreach adicional para hacer la llamada. Tu bucle while va iterando por cada elemento, y crea un array `$array_llamada`. Lo que te comenta @David en su solucion es que en lugar de hacer la llamada, asignes ese array_llamada a otro general. Luego, fuera del while, llamas a tu metodo conexion_creator. La cosa esta que ahora enviarás un array de registros, por lo que el metodo que hace el almacenamiento debe componer la consulta de tipo Insert. y ahi SI vas a necesitar ese for.

Comment: @Jakala por lo que se ve en el código se envía el array por post via curl, no haría falta armar un sql ( hay q ver si el endpoint soporta múltiples registros, pero ese es otro cantar )